# ¿como evito que desaparezcan los otros menu al desplegar dropdown paginas?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

Tengo problemas al momento de desplegar el menu **paginas**. Me muestra todos los `<li>` que estan dentro del *dropdown* menu proyectos sin hacer *click* y tambien desaparecen los otros menus cuando paso con mouse en **paginas**. Los menus afectados son **nuestro equipo**, **mision y vision**,etc

Se supone que la primera imagen es cuando paso con mouse por **paginas** y me despliega automáticamente los menus de **proyectos** y la segunda imagen es como deberia verse, haciendo click y verse todos los menus, incluyendo los de **paginas** y **proyectos** juntos.

[image: ese cuando paso el mouse por paginas, y me despliega automaticamente el menu proyectos]
[image: a si deberia verse:(]

```
<!-- Navbar Start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top py-0 pe-5">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand ps-5 me-0">
        <h3 class="text-white m-0">DHM Asesorias</h3>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-0" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">Inicio</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Nosotros</a>
            <a href="service.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Servicios</a>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Paginas</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light m-0">

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Proyectos </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <a href="feature.html" class="dropdown-item">Nuestro Equipo</a>
                    <a href="mision_vision.html" class="dropdown-item">Mision y Vision</a>
                    <a href="valores.html" class="dropdown-item">Valores</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Otros Servicios</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contacto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navbar End -->
```

este es mi javascript

```
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')
dropdowns.forEach((dd)=>{
    dd.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var el = this.nextElementSibling
        el.style.display = el.style.display==='block'?'none':'block'
    })
})
```

Comment: se supone que la primera imagen es cuando paso con mouse por paginas y me despliega automaticamente los menus de proyectos y la segunda imagen es como deberia verse, haciendo click y verse todo los menu incluyendo los de paginas y proyectos juntos

Comment: cual es el problema especifico? si tu menu principal se encuentra desplegado sin hacer click debe ser porque todos los elementos entran en la pantalla entonces el boton desplegable se oculta. Prueba achicar el viewport, cuando los elementos del nav no tengan mas espacio se mostrara el boton desplegable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes setear con la propiedad [data-bs-auto-close="false"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior) para evitar el cierre automático de los dropdown

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top py-0 pe-5">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand ps-5 me-0">
        <h3 class="text-white m-0">DHM Asesorias</h3>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler me-0" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto p-4 p-lg-0">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">Inicio</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Nosotros</a>
            <a href="service.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Servicios</a>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  data-bs-auto-close="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Paginas</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light m-0">

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"  data-bs-auto-close="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Proyectos </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="project.html">Hola</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <a href="feature.html" class="dropdown-item">Nuestro Equipo</a>
                    <a href="mision_vision.html" class="dropdown-item">Mision y Vision</a>
                    <a href="valores.html" class="dropdown-item">Valores</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Otros Servicios</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contacto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah, vale vale pa Gracias, leeré un poco más de docs documentación

Comment: me di cuenta, que cuando lo amplio a imagen en pc pantalla completa me sucede como en la primera imagen:(